Adding a nested list with two tiers to a table cell
I'm trying to create a nested list with multiple tiers (indents) within a table in markdown, like the image below (created in Microsoft Word):
enter image description here
I have this Markdown code but can't seem to make the "Naturalized 2019" bullet indented when it's within a table.
| # | Name | Description |
|--|----|-----------------|
| 1 | John | - 29 <br/> - American <br/> - Naturalized 2019   |

It just comes out like below:
enter image description here
Outside of a table it seems to work fine
- 29
- American
  - Naturalized 2019

and appears as:
enter image description here
Any suggestions?
